# Small Axis arrows in PGFplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to draw small arrows (through a macro probably), to show the coordinate directions like the plot below. It would be nice to have the option to turn on/off the grids as well.

The MWE for generating the plot:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
[view = {120}{10}
,grid = both
]
\addplot3[surf] {x^2+y^2};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A straight forward way is to set appropriate coordinates in the `rel axis cs` and then draw arrows outside the `axis` environement, such that the arrows don't get clipped by the axis.

The length of the hand drawn axis lines is controlled via `\axislength`. Replace `\def\axislength{.2}` with `\def\axislength{.3}` for instance to make them longer.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\def\axislength{.2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view = {120}{10},ticks=none,axis lines=none]
    \coordinate (O) at (rel axis cs:1,0,0);
    \coordinate (x) at (rel axis cs:1,\axislength,0);
    \coordinate (y) at (rel axis cs:1-\axislength,0,0);
    \coordinate (z) at (rel axis cs:1,0,\axislength);
    \addplot3[surf] {x^2+y^2};
  \end{axis}
  \draw[->] (O) -- (x) node[above] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (O) -- (y) node[above] {$y$};
  \draw[->] (O) -- (z) node[right] {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks @HenriMenke!  Can we make the axis lines and labels disappear? Further, can we make the arrow length independent to the coordinate `xmin`,`xmax`, etc?

Comment: @M.Reza try `ticks=none` for hiding the ticks. If you want to get rid of the box around the plot, try `axis lines=none`.

Comment: @M.Reza See my updated answer.